# Sending both files and model from Angular 4 to ASP.NET Core backend

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, multipartform-data, angular-http

I've been trying to make a form that contains both file inputs (in this case images) and text inputs. Text inputs are part of the model which I want to send to server. On the backend I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0.

Here is my backend code:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostEditProfile([FromForm] EditProfileViewModel model, IFormFile profileImage, IFormFile bannerImage)
{
     //Some code
}
```

When I call this API using Postman (where I set model's properties and images in form-data), everything works fine. But when I try to call it using Angular code, all the parameters are null. Here is my Angular 4 code:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for (var propertyName in editProfile) {
    if (editProfile[propertyName]){
        formData.append(propertyName, editProfile[propertyName].toString());
    } 
}
formData.append('profileImage', profileImage);
formData.append('bannerImage', bannerImage);

return this.authHttp.post(this.baseUrl + 'api/Account/PostEditProfile', formData)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => {
        var userInfo = response.json() as UserInfo;
        this.setUserInfo(userInfo);
        return userInfo.userName;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

When I looked at the request using Fiddler, I noticed that when I send request using Angular 4, Content-type header is not set to multipart/form-data (and when I use Postman it is). I've tried setting it, but it was set to application/json again.

I've also tried without [FromForm], but also no luck. I'm not sure what to do next.